# Как разделить массив на 3 части и скомбинировать ассоциативный массив имея массив с ключами в PHP?

Tags: php, массивы

Имеется два массива:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => Wooow!
    [2] => Alex
    [3] => 4
    [4] => Good
    [5] => Pete
    [6] => 2
    [7] => Bad
    [8] => John
    [9] => 1
    [10] => Shit
    [11] => Steve
)

Array
(
    [0] => rating
    [1] => comment
    [2] => person
    [3] => rating
    [4] => comment
    [5] => person
    [6] => rating
    [7] => comment
    [8] => person
    [9] => rating
    [10] => comment
    [11] => person
)
```

Как мне получить такой массив?

```
Array

(
    [0]=>Array(
         [rating]=>5
         [comment]=>Wooow!
         [person]=>Alex  
     )

    [1]=>Array(
         [rating]=>4
         [comment]=>Good
         [person]=>Pete  
     )

    [2]=>Array(
         [rating]=>2
         [comment]=>Bad
         [person]=>John  
     )
    ...
)
```

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не уверен что второй массив именно такой вам нужен, но хозяин-барин:

```
$a = Array
(
    0 => 5,
    1 => 'Wooow!',
    2 => 'Alex',
    3 => 4,
    4 => 'Good',
    5 => 'Pete',
    6 => 2,
    7 => 'Bad',
    8 => 'John',
    9 => 1,
    10 => 'Shit',
    11 => 'Steve'
);

$b = Array
(
    0 => 'rating',
    1 => 'comment',
    2 => 'person',
    3 => 'rating',
    4 => 'comment',
    5 => 'person',
    6 => 'rating',
    7 => 'comment',
    8 => 'person',
    9 => 'rating',
    10 => 'comment',
    11 => 'person1'
);
$count = 3; // сколько в дольке будет

// Вариант 1
$b = array_slice($b, 0, $count);
$c = array_map( function($v) use($b) {return array_combine($b, $v);}, 
                array_chunk($a, $count)
              );


// Вариант 2
// Отличается от первого, что использует весь $b
$c = array_chunk($a, $count);
foreach ($c as &$v) {
    $v = array_combine(array_slice($b, 0, $count), $v);
    $b = array_slice($b, $count);
}

// Вывод
var_dump($c);
```

Comment: Спасибо, похожий вариант я смог реализовать с явным указанием количества колонок. Желательно бы без явного указания. Второй массив не принципиально такой, можно первые три значения.

Comment: @Евгений если в `$b` - 3 значения, то `$count = count($b);` - без явного указания :)

Comment: Благодарю, я так и знал, что все до безобразного просто).

Comment: @Евгений а откуда число 3 взялось? с воздуха? все равно где-то циферку 3 придется прописать))) Если вы говорите про уникальные поля этого массива (а их как раз 3), то так `$b = array_unique($b);`. Если так, то будешь должен плюсик ;)

Comment: Спасибо, попробую решить.

Comment: Все гуд, благодарю!